# Inconsistent behaviour of window.innerWidth in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am getting an inconsistent value for window.innerWidth in Chrome from when a page first loads (not in cache) vs when it is reloaded (from cache).  Any ideas why.

Hear is my simple HTML file:

```
<html>
     <body>
           <script>
                  alert(window.innerHeight)
           </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

If I run this in the Incognito window (to ensure it is not cached) I get a value x, and then when I refresh the value is always x + 40.

What's happening?

Comment: Maybe different window height and content that requires scrollbar in one window but not in other? Just using your sample code I don't observe this behaviour.